# Linear Interpolation and finding $r^2$ for a case where $r^2$ is nearly $1$

Tags: statistics

Below is a problem I did. I hope I did it correctly. I was able to confirm I had the correct least-square line with R. However, R got a different value for $r^2$. The script is included at the end of the post.
Problem:
Fit a least-square line to the data given below with $x$ as the independent variable and $y$ as the dependent variable. Then find $r^2$.
Here is a list of $x$ values:
$$ 1, \, 2, \, 3,\, 4 $$
Here is a list of $y$ values:
$$ 2, \, 4, \, 6, \, 9 $$

Answer:

We want to find an equation of the form:
$$ y = bx + a $$
To do this, we set up the following system of two equations.
\begin{align*}
\sum y &= an + b \sum x \\
\sum xy &= a \sum x + b \sum x^2
\end{align*}
We now find the things we can find and come up with two equations.
\begin{align*}
\sum y &= 2 + 4 + 6 + 9 = 21 \\
n &= 4 \\
\sum x &= 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 = 10 \\
\sum xy &= 1(2) + 2(4) + 3(6) + 4(9) = 2 + 8 + 18 + 36 = 28 + 36 \\
\sum xy &= 64 \\
\sum x^2 &= 1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 + 4^2 = 1 + 4 + 9 + 16 = 14 + 16 = 30 \\
\end{align*}
We now find the things we can find and come up with two equations.
\begin{align*}
21 &= 4a + 10b \\
64 &=10a + 30b \\
4a &= 21 - 10b \\
a &= \frac{21 - 10b}{4} \\
10 \left( \frac{21 - 10b}{4} \right)  + 30b &= 64 \\
5 \left( \frac{21 - 10b}{2} \right)  + 30b &= 64 \\
5 \left( 21 - 10b \right)  + 60b &= 128 \\
105 - 50b + 60b &= 128 \\
105 + 10b &= 128 \\
b &= \frac{23}{10} \\
a &= \frac{21 - 10 \left(  \frac{23}{10} \right) }{4} = \frac{21 - 23}{4} \\
a &= -\frac{1}{2}
\end{align*}
Hence our equation is:
$$ y = \left( \frac{23}{10}\right) x  - \frac{1}{2} $$
Now we want to find $r^2$.
$$ r^2 = 1 - \frac{\sum ( y - y_{est})^2}{\sum( y - \overline{y})^2 } $$
Here is a list of values for $y_{est}$:
$$ \frac{9}{5} \frac{41}{10} \frac{32}{5} \frac{87}{10}$$
\begin{align*}
\sum ( y - y_{est})^2 &= \left( 2 - \frac{9}{5} \right) ^2 + \left( 4 - \frac{41}{10} \right) ^2 + \left( 6 - \frac{32}{5} \right) ^2
+ \left( 9 - \frac{87}{10} \right) ^2 \\
\sum ( y - y_{est})^2 &= \left( \frac{10 - 9}{5} \right) ^2 + \left( \frac{40 - 41}{10} \right) ^2
+ \left( \frac{30 - 32}{5} \right) ^2 + \left( \frac{90 - 87}{10} \right) ^2 \\
\sum ( y - y_{est})^2 &= \left( \frac{1}{5} \right) ^2 + \left( \frac{-1}{10} \right) ^2 + \left( \frac{-2}{5} \right) ^2
+ \left( \frac{3}{10} \right) ^2 \\
\sum ( y - y_{est})^2 &= \frac{1}{25} + \frac{1}{100} + \frac{4}{25} + \frac{9}{100} = \frac{4 + 1 + 16 + 9}{100} \\
\sum ( y - y_{est})^2 &= \frac{30}{100} = \frac{3}{10} \\
\overline{y} &= \frac{21}{4} \\
\sum( y - \overline{y})^2  &= \left( 2 -  \frac{21}{4} \right)^2 + \left( 4 -  \frac{21}{4} \right)^2
+ \left( 6 -  \frac{21}{4} \right)^2 + \left( 9 -  \frac{21}{4} \right)^2 \\
\sum( y - \overline{y})^2  &= \left( \frac{8 - 21}{4} \right)^2 + \left( \frac{16 - 21}{4} \right)^2
+ \left( \frac{24 - 21}{4} \right)^2 + \left( \frac{36-21}{4} \right)^2 \\
\sum( y - \overline{y})^2  &= \left( \frac{-13}{4} \right)^2 + \left( \frac{-5}{4} \right)^2
+ \left( \frac{3}{4} \right)^2 + \left( \frac{15}{4} \right)^2 \\
\sum( y - \overline{y})^2  &= \frac{ 139 + 25 + 9 + 225}{16} =  \frac{398}{16} \\
\sum( y - \overline{y})^2  &= \frac{199}{8} \\
r^2 &= 1 - \frac{\frac{3}{10}}{ \frac{199}{8} } = 1 - \frac{3(8)}{10(199)} \\
r^2 &=  1 - \frac{3(4)}{5(199)} = \frac{5(199) - 12}{5(199)} \\
r^2 &= \frac{983 } {995} \\
r^2 &\doteq 0.9879397
\end{align*}

Here is my R script:

```
x = c(  3 , 5 , 6 , 8 , 9 , 11 )
y = c (2 , 3 , 4 , 6 , 5 , 8 )
lm( y ~ x )
s = lm( y ~ x )
summary(s)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a computation mistake in the penultimate line of the evaluation of $\Sigma(y-\bar{y})^2$. $(-13)^2$ is 169 and not 139. The correct computation would yield a value of $r^2 = \frac{529}{535} \approx 0.98878$ which matches with the value reported by the R script.